# Cannot create a new child form in C# windows form

Tags: asp.net, winforms, c#-4.0

In my windows form application, I have already added a child form that appears on the center location of the parent form when I click on add a new product button. Now, I want to add a new child form with a different name where I can capture the existing details of the product for editing them.

My problem is that when I create a new child form for editing products, I keep its name different i.e childEditProduct but when I save it, both the child forms (childAddProduct and childEditProduct) appears with the same name.

How can I prevent the IDE from renaming the existing child form?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. Is it ASP.net Web Forms or Windows Forms Application Aka Desktop Application ?(talking for Windows Forms) if i understand you right you are trying to add and edit from 1 form. so at that form when you pick data.you can simply change form's name in to editProduct and for Add make form Caption Add new. just place that simple row of code in your methods so program will rename it. Also prove some code.

Comment: @HilalIbrahim it is windows form application, not web form. I am done with it now. I placed the new childForm in a sub-directory under the forms folder.

Comment: Okay so Windows forms aren't ASP.net windows forms is Windows Forms. Good luck

Comment: you should share the code otherwise we can't see the problem

Comment: I am not talking about code yet. I was talking about the problem with IDE.

Comment: i never had a problem like you said i put all of my forms in a folder and call it Forms.

Comment: Give a try to child forms. Create two child forms within that folder and then see the magic!

Comment: i have an application with 7 child forms in same folder and no problem at all

Comment: So how did you manage them? I keep the isMDIContainer false for both the child forms as I do want them to be the subforms. As soon I am creating the 2nd child form, the first child form is also renamed. If you can suggest me a solution to this problem, I am sure I will use both these forms in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Due to some restrictions, I think Asp.Net do not allow multiple child forms within the same folder. I have created another folder within Forms folder and then I added the 2nd child form for editing a product and it works.

I am still looking for a perfect answer that can clear the ambiguity that was the reason behind this problem.